WinUI 3 How to create a usercontrols library
I created a control library of user controls, but it not working out of solution.
When I use it in other solutions I get this error: 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'XAML parsing failed.''
Thanks

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:Walkthrough—Create a C# component with WinUI 3 controls, and consume it from a C++/WinRT app that uses the Windows App SDK. And this error can happen if there is an issue in MainWindow.xaml not detected by the XAML compiler. Refer to the thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/831836/microsoft-ui-xaml-markup-xamlparseexception-xaml-p

Can you elaborate on how you are using the library?

@Jeaninez-MSFT in your link "Consumption from packaged apps that use a separate Windows Application Packaging (WAP) project is not currently supported". My example is minimal, not prone to errors

@AndrewKeepCoding - I created a new class library project. In it I added a new user control file with a textbox only. I build it. I referenced it (.dll file) in other new project in other application. It not work.

Try creating a NuGet package of your control library:

Set the current configuration to Release.
Right click the control library project and select Pack.
Inside the bin/Release folder, get the create NuGet package file. (*.nupkg)
Create a folder to store your local NuGet packages, "C:\LocalNuGetPackages" for example.
Right click the app project and select Manage NuGet Packages....
Click the GEAR icon located at the right side of Package source:.
Register the local folder as a package source.
Install the control library as a NuGet package.

